# Karma Sutra Game Version 2.0

Tags: javascript, html, game

I have refactored the [code for this game](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/145716/karma-sutra-game/145725?noredirect=1#comment273812_145725) thanks to some great suggestions from [woxxom](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/113168/woxxom)

Now, once again, any suggestions still welcome. I am going to be improving the UX as a next phase (giving hints to the user etc).

I have also improved the consistency of naming IDs and using single/double quotes etc.

There was one slight oversight with woxxom's code in that he did this:

```
function restart() {
container.className = 'female';
sectionTitle.textContent = 'Ladies';
sectionTitle.classList.remove('tada');
sectionTitle.classList.add('slideInLeft');

hide(answer);

choices.ladies = [];
choices.gents = [];

// ladiesChoice and gentsChoice are not defined here
deanimateChoice(ladiesChoice);
deanimateChoice(gentsChoice);


choices.forEach(function(c) { element.disabled = false; });
}
```

However, the rest of the code was spot on! Here it is in its entirety:

```
(function(){

// Initializtion
var intro = getByID('intro');
var container = getByID('mainContainer');
var positionsContainer = getByID('positions');
var sectionTitle = getByID('sectionTitle');
var results = getByID('results');
var chosenPositions = getByID('chosenPositions');

// create positions
var positions = [
    "Sixty-Nine",
"Missionary",
"Doggy style",
"Rodeo",
"Reverse Cowgirl",
"Girl on top",
"Zeus",
"Venus",
"Workout"
];

// and insert them into the DOM
positionsContainer.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', 
    positions.map(function(position, i){
        return '    <button id="position-' + i + '" ' +
                            'class="choice-buttons">' + position +
                      '</button>';
    }).join('')
);

var MAX_CHOICES = 2;
var choices = positionsContainer.querySelectorAll('button');
choices.ladies = [];
choices.gents = [];

getByID('play').onclick = play;
getByID('restart').onclick = restart;
choices.forEach(function(c) { c.onclick = choose; });

// only the intro is shown on game start
hide(positionsContainer);
hide(sectionTitle);
hide(results);

container.className = 'female';

// overall game control
function play() {
    hide(intro);
    show(sectionTitle);
    show(positionsContainer);
}

// in-game control
function choose() {
    // prevent duplicate choices
    this.disabled = true;

    // Ladies first
    if(choices.ladies.length < MAX_CHOICES) {
        choices.ladies.push(this.id);

        // change the classname to "male" once female choices reach 2
        if(choices.ladies.length == MAX_CHOICES) {
            container.className = 'male';
            sectionTitle.textContent = 'Gents';
            sectionTitle.classList.remove('slideInLeft');
            sectionTitle.classList.add('slideInRight');
        }           
    } else {
        choices.gents.push(this.id);

        if(choices.gents.length == MAX_CHOICES) {
            showResults();
        }
    }
}

// results
function showResults() {
    // change the classname to results once the gents selections reach 2
    container.className = 'results';
    sectionTitle.textContent = 'Results';
    sectionTitle.classList.remove('slideInRight');
    sectionTitle.classList.add('tada');

    choices.forEach(function(c) { c.disabled = true });

    // randomly get a selection from each array
    do {
        var ladiesIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * MAX_CHOICES);
        var gentsIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * MAX_CHOICES);
    } while (ladiesIndex === gentsIndex);

    var ladiesChoice = getByID(choices.ladies[ladiesIndex]);
    var gentsChoice = getByID(choices.gents[gentsIndex]);

    animateChoice(ladiesChoice);
    animateChoice(gentsChoice);

    // print out the final choices
    chosenPositions.textContent = "Looks like you'll be doing " + 
            ladiesChoice.textContent + " and " + 
            gentsChoice.textContent + 
            " tonight!";
    show(results);
}

function restart() {
    container.className = 'female';
    sectionTitle.textContent = 'Ladies';
    sectionTitle.classList.remove('tada');
    sectionTitle.classList.add('slideInLeft');
    sectionTitle.classList.remove('slideInRight');
    hide(results);

    choices.ladies = [];
    choices.gents = [];

    choices.forEach(function(c) { 
        c.disabled = false; 
        // somewhat crude approach at the moment for removing the classes
        c.classList.remove('selected', 'animated', 'infinite', 'pulse');
    });
}

// utility functions
function getByID(ID) {
    return document.getElementById(ID);
}

function show(element) {
    element.style.display = 'block';
}

function hide(element) {
    element.style.display = 'none';
}

function animateChoice(element) {
    element.classList.add('selected', 'animated', 'infinite', 'pulse');
}

function deanimateChoice(element) {
    element.classList.remove('selected', 'animated', 'infinite', 'pulse');
}

})();
```